# .zshrc: Setting up rvm

Tags: macos, zsh, rvm

I had installed rvm on my Mac at a time where I was still using bash. Now I completely switched to zsh. The rvm home page however gives *bash*  as requirement.

Nevertheless, [this rvm site](https://rvm.io/integration/zsh) promises that the rvm functions should also work with a sufficiently new zsh. Since I'm using zsh 5.8.1, I decided to give it a try.

Indeed it seems that the rvm functions surprisingly are written in a way so that they  work equally well under bash and zsh. However, when I start a new terminal - where I load the rvm functions using

```
set -u
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

I get a few warnings about unset parameters. I could remove nearly all of them by defining them to be empty, but there is one warning left which causes headache:

> __function_on_stack:2: FUNCNAME[*]: parameter not set

`FUNCNAME` is a predefined bash-array, not present in zsh, and rvm seems to need it for inspecting the stack. Now I can of course make the warning go away by doing a

```
FUNCNAME=()
```

before sourcing, but since FUNCNAME is supposed to be managed by the shell, this setting would most likely break some functionality.

I am aware that I would never have noticed this problem, if I hadn't tested my code with `set -u`, and I want to emphasize that my goal is not to have that nasty warning be invisible, but to ensure that I end up with a stable setup of rvm. In particular, FUNCNAME seems to be used a lot by rvm.

Is there anybody out there who uses rvm under zsh, and can recommend to me what to do?

Comment: Does this same thing happen through the .zshrc auto-sourcing on terminal launch?

Comment: @NorseGaud: Sure. Since I specify in the terminal configuration (preferences), which zsh command should be executed by the Terminal, I would be surprised if there were a difference. Actually, you can grep the rvm functions and **see** that there are a lot of occurances of `FUNCNAME` in them. It is clear that this part was explicitly written for bash.